# How to suppress warnings for a whole module at a time in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, android-studio, suppress-warnings

Every time I commit, Android Studio first checks the whole project. I am using one module which generates over 400 warnings. I don't plan on fixing the issues causing the warnings, since most of them are not important at all.

This slows development quite  a lot, so:

**Is there a way to suppress checks on a whole module at the same time in Android Studio**

**If not, is there a way to blacklist / whitelist certain directories from these inspections?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you commit, there is checkbox to do not analyse the code:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, so there is no way to switch it off per module or directory?

Comment: Because it would be useful if the Analyze > Inspect Code.. avoided that module/directory too.

Comment: You can switch inspection at all, but there is no such granularity per module or project